# About Mysql performance in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, performance, codeigniter

When i ust to work in procedural mode (without codeigniter), in my queries i ust to inform the fields that i needed from the table, because the table had like more than 80 fields. For example,

```
select US_NOME, US_CODIGO from USERS
```

However i'v been working with codeigniter and my friend says i can simply get all fields from the table, without worry about speed.

It doesn't sound's right, i mean there's like 5000+ registry's in this table.

We don't need to specify fields in codeigniter? No problem about performance?

Comment: There are two issues at work here.  The time needed to execute the query strategy in MySQL might not increase that much by adding more columns, but the network time needed to send that result set to your app would certainly increase in going from 2 to 5000 columns.  If you don't need all that data, don't send it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's about 80 columns not 5000 columns. 5000 is number of rows.